# Pandas replacing values in columns, but to_replace argument is a tuple containing tuples

Tags: python, pandas, replace, data-cleaning, iterable

I'm decoding values from NLSY 79. They're occupational industries. Each industry has a number of occupations; for example: all occupations from 17 to 29 are in the Agriculture, Forestry, & Fishery Industry. I've tried three strategies, but two return errors and the third doesn't store the value in the data frame.

The execution code looks like this (Survey respondents could list up to 5 jobs, all of which are included in the data)

```
df[['Job1', 'Job2', 'Job3', 'Job4', 'Job5']].replace(to_replace=jobs['code'], value=jobs['true'], inplace=True)
```

Strategy 1

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

```
jobs = {'code': ( tuple(range(17,29)), ... )
        'true': ( 'Agriculture, Forestry & Fisheries', ... )
```

Strategy 2

> TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'range'

```
jobs = {'code': ( range(17,29), ... )
        'true': ( 'Agriculture, Forestry & Fisheries', ... )
```

Strategy 3

> SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

```
jobs = {'code': ( any(tuple(range(17, 29))), any(tuple(range(47, 58))), ... )
        'true': ( 'Agriculture, Forestry & Fisheries', 'Mining', ... )
```

I think a tweak to the third strategy/execution code would be best, but I'm still new to coding and am not sure what it would be. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

```
Input:
        Job1      ...  
0       339       ...  
1       757       ...  
2       739       ...  
3       448       ...  

Desired Output:

        Job1            ...  
0       Utilities       ...  
1       Professional    ...  
2       Professional    ...  
3       Retail          ...

job = {'code': (list(range(17, 29)),
                   list(range(47, 58)),
                   list(range(67, 78)), ...)
       'true': ('Agriculture, Forestry & Fisheries',
                  'Mining',
                  'Construction', ...)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
df1
        Job1
0       20
1       50
2       70

job = {'code': (list(range(17, 29)),
                   list(range(47, 58)),
                   list(range(67, 78))),
       'true': ('Agriculture, Forestry & Fisheries',
                  'Mining',
                  'Construction')}

pd_replace = pd.DataFrame(job).explode('code')
df1.replace(dict(zip(pd_replace['code'], pd_replace['true'])))

                                Job1
0  Agriculture, Forestry & Fisheries
1                             Mining
2                       Construction
```

Comment: Worked and cut the run time in half! One problem is that I can only do it for one column at a time so I have to iterate through the 5 job columns. Is there something  I can do to keep this to one line?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Not the fastest method, but it works.

```
job = {'code': (list(range(17, 29)), ...),  
       'true': ('Agriculture, Forestry & Fisheries', ...)}  

    for i, x in enumerate(job['code']):  
        for key in df_jobs:  
            df[key].replace(to_replace=x, value=[job['true'][i]]*len(x), inplace=True)
```